# Insert Query Values Into Grid (mysql + php)

Tags: php, mysql, grid

I have a DB table with the following fields:

```
SeasonId | Number | PlayerId
```

And my HTML table is a grid with SeasonId's on the x-axis (along the top) and Numbers 1-99 on the y-axis (down the side).

What I'm going for is to place the value of "PlayerId" in the cell where SeasonId + and Number intersect. For example:

```
SeasonId=8 | Number=27 | PlayerId=215
```

This record would show in the 8th season column in the 27th row.

Anyone know a good way of going about this?

Comment: use a `<table>`. you can address rows/cells individually using standard DOM operations if need be. But if this data is coming from the db, just do proper sorting in the db so you can naturally just spit out the table's html in the proper order without having to "jump around" addressing random cells.

Comment: How would sorting work if not all Numbers have records? Say in SeasonId=8, there is no record for Number=15...then you couldn't just "spit out" the values as they would need to skip the 15th cell during the loop. Unless I'm mis-understanding something.

Comment: then you need a bit of extra logic to detect gaps in the data and spit out empty rows/cells as needed.

Comment: Sure enough. I can do most of this with php logic. Thanks.